# Can the union of uncountable infinite sets be a countable infinite set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

> Can the union of uncountable infinite sets be a countable infinite set?

If there is such a set, I would be grateful if you answer the question by giving an example.

If the question is too simple, I apologize.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry for English. I fixed.

Comment: If you ask for all of them to be nonempty, no

Comment: No it cannot, the union of uncountable sets must be uncountable too.

Comment: that is clear because if their union is countable then the restriction of the injection to N, to each of the unioned sets would be clearly an injection to N, i.e. they would be countable. A contradiction.

Comment: well are subsets of countable sets countable?

Comment: To edit the question, I need help: I mean, The set has an infinite number of integers. But the elements are not subject to a specific function. So it is not countable.

Comment: Yes, of course, just restrict the injection to N to those subsets.

Comment: if their union is countable, then there is an injection from that Union to N, because that's what countable means by definition, so just restrict this injection to any of the unioned sets and that set would be countable also, which contradicts your premise of each of those sets being uncountable. So their union cannot be countable!

Comment: Just checking we're not answering the wrong thing: you do mean a union of uncountable sets, not a union of **uncountably many** sets?

Comment: (For uncountably many countable sets, we could just point out that $\mathbb N$ is the union of its uncountably many subsets.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be one of the uncountable sets, and let $B$ be their union.

Suppose $B$  is countable.

By the definition of set union, every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$: that is, $A\subseteq B$.

Therefore $B$ is a countable set with an uncountable subset, which is a contradiction.

Therefore $B$ cannot be countable.

---

**Note:** This relies on the theorem that every subset of a countable set is countable. The easiest way to see why that's true is to imagine counting the original set but skipping elements which aren't in the subset. A proof just involves expressing that more formally.

Answer (score 0):

Unions cannot decrease the cardinality of a set, so suppose $A_i$ are uncountable then the finite union has cardinality:
$$ |\bigcup\limits_{i=0}^{N} A_i|\geq |A_i|$$
for any of the $A_i$. Which means they are definitely uncountable.

Comment: How are you just carrying the proof for finite sets and extending for infinite set? What is the definition of cardinality for infinite set whatever it is , but it is not number of an ordered set?

Comment: The pigeon hole principle is valid for finite sets  but is not valid for infinite , an example is the **infinite hotel paradox**

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the OP meant the *intersection* of uncountable sets.  If so, then certainly it's possible with a countable infinity of input sets.  The $p$-adic integers for any prime $p$ are uncountably infinite, but the intersection of all such sets for all primes $p$ is just the ordinary integers.

Comment: Or even with just two sets, like $A=\mathbb R_{>0}$ and $B=\mathbb R_{<0} \cup \mathbb N$ (though this makes $B$ very much an invented-for-a-proof set!)

Comment: (I'm unsure of the usual notation. I mean positive reals in one set, and natural numbers and negative reals in the other, so they just have $\mathbb N$ in common.)